# How to properly capture output of process using pwntools

Tags: python, exploit, pwntools

I'm currently confused on how to use the pwntools library for python3 for exploiting programs - mainly sending the input into a vulnerable program.
This is my current python script.

```
from pwn import *
def executeVuln():
    vulnBin = process("./buf2", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    vulnBin.sendlineafter(': ','A'*90)
    output = vulnBin.recvline(timeout=5)

    print(output)

executeVuln()
```

The program I'm trying to exploit is below - This isn't about how to exploit the program, more on using the script to properly automate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define BUFSIZE 176
#define FLAGSIZE 64

void flag(unsigned int arg1, unsigned int arg2) {
  char buf[FLAGSIZE];
  FILE *f = fopen("flag.txt","r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    printf("Flag File is Missing. Problem is Misconfigured, please contact an Admin if you are running this on the shell server.\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  fgets(buf,FLAGSIZE,f);
  if (arg1 != 0xDEADBEEF)
    return;
  if (arg2 != 0xC0DED00D)
    return;
  printf(buf);
}

void vuln(){
  char buf[BUFSIZE];
  gets(buf);
  puts(buf);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

  gid_t gid = getegid();
  setresgid(gid, gid, gid);

  puts("Please enter your string: ");
  vuln();
  return 0;
}
```

The process is opened fine.
sendlineafter blocks until it sends the line and so if it doesn't match it waits indefinitely. However, it runs fine and so the input should be sent.
output should receive 90 A's from recvLine due to

`puts(buffer)`   outputting the inputted string.

However, all that is returned is
`b''`, which seems to indicate that the vulnerable program isn't receiving the input and returning an empty string.

Anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

With the above programs, I'm getting the `print(output)` as `b'\n'` (not `b''`) and here is the explanation for it.

The `puts()` statement outputs a `newline` character at the end and it is not read by the `sendlineafter()` call, which in-turn leads the stray `newline` character to be read by the below `recvline()` printing `b'\n'`.

Why the `newline` character is not by read by `sendlineafter()`? Because the `sendlineafter()` is just a combination of `recvuntil()` and `sendline()`, where `recvuntil()` only reads till `delimiter` leaving characters after. ([pwntools docs](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/tubes.html#pwnlib.tubes.tube.tube.sendlineafter))

So the solution for this is to read the newline character with `sendlineafter()` like below (or by calling `recvline()` twice),

```
from pwn import *

def executeVuln():
    vulnBin = process("./buf2", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    vulnBin.sendlineafter(b': \n',b'A'*90)
    output = vulnBin.recvline(timeout=5)

    print(output)

executeVuln()
```

**Output:**

```
[+] Starting local process './buf2': pid 3493
[*] Process './buf2' stopped with exit code 0 (pid 3493)
b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n'
```

**Note:**
I added the strings as bytes in `sendlineafter()` to remove the below `BytesWarning`.

```
program.py:5: BytesWarning: Text is not bytes; assuming ASCII, no guarantees. See https://docs.pwntools.com/#bytes
  vulnBin.sendlineafter(': \n','A'*90)
```

Comment: I know this might be very late to answer this question but I stumbled upon a similar kind of issue. And I hope this answer might help any future visitors.